# Constructive proof of Lebesgue

Tags: probability, measure-theory

I started to learn about probability, and in one example there was a circle such that the length of thr circle is one, and the lecturer in this video said that it is possible to find a countable union of congruent sets  of the circle, such that the the union equals the whole circle and the sets are mutually disjoint (I may understood some details in an incorrect way), also he mentioned that the constructive proof of this is made by Lebesgue.
I tried to search for it but couldnt find because I dont know the exact definitions of what I look for, but I guess that's a well known thing for people exprienced with probability and measure theory. So I was hoping that somebody here will understand what I talk about and coul share a link for further reading.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is the standard construction of a non-measurable set; google will have links... (if there's one to wikipedia start there)

Comment: See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vitali_set